# Join two pandas dataframe based on their indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes that I am attempting to join. Both have the same length and index.

```
df1.index 

RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1857, step=1)

df2.index

RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1857, step=1)
```

I do the following to only join columns that don't overlap.

```
cols = df2.columns.difference(df1.columns)
cols

df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2[cols], left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

While `df_merged` has the shape that I expect, `1857`, there are several rows that are `NaNs`. `df1` has no `NaN` rows.

What am I missing here? How I add merge dataframes based on indices?

Comment: Try `df_concat = pd.concat([df1, df2[cols]], axis=1)`

Comment: your syntax for merge is incorrect. reference here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: @JonathanLeon. Why do you think the syntax is incorrect?

Comment: The examples in the link all have df1.merge(df2….), however if pd.merge(df1,df2….) is viable solution I’ll look into that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Although your code works well, try to use `df.join` or `pd.concat`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (10, 4)), columns=list('CDEF'))

cols = df2.columns.difference(df1.columns)
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2[cols], left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df1.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1)

>>> df2.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1)

>>> cols
Index(['E', 'F'], dtype='object')

>>> df_merged
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  8  3  4  3  6  3
1  2  5  3  4  5  9
2  4  1  7  7  5  1
3  2  4  6  7  7  8
4  6  6  4  8  5  8
5  8  6  8  4  4  5
6  7  9  7  7  6  6
7  8  4  2  3  7  1
8  5  7  1  1  8  5
9  8  2  5  8  5  9
```

**Join**

```
>>> df1.join(df2[cols])
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  8  3  4  3  6  3
1  2  5  3  4  5  9
2  4  1  7  7  5  1
3  2  4  6  7  7  8
4  6  6  4  8  5  8
5  8  6  8  4  4  5
6  7  9  7  7  6  6
7  8  4  2  3  7  1
8  5  7  1  1  8  5
9  8  2  5  8  5  9
```

**Concat**

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2[cols]], axis=1)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  8  3  4  3  6  3
1  2  5  3  4  5  9
2  4  1  7  7  5  1
3  2  4  6  7  7  8
4  6  6  4  8  5  8
5  8  6  8  4  4  5
6  7  9  7  7  6  6
7  8  4  2  3  7  1
8  5  7  1  1  8  5
9  8  2  5  8  5  9
```